# iOS get actual size of image from Assets based on device screen size

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, assets

I am working on an `iOS` app that uses many images for icons. I have added images to Assets and accessed them from my views.

I need to know the actual size of the image that will be displayed on the screen at run time. When I create `UIImage` object like this:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "my_image")
```

then access its size, I always get the `1x` size - on all devices with different screen sizes -. As I know, `iOS` loads the appropriate image size based on the screen size at run time.

So, how can I get the actual image size that will be rendered on the screen instead of always getting the default size ?

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-find-an-aspect-fit-images-size-inside-an-image-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of `UIImage` is in points. To get actual size in pixels, you can multiply it by the scale of your screen - 2.0 or 3.0 for Retina displays - like so

```
let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
let sizeInPixels = CGSize(width: imageSize.width * scale, height: imageSize.height * scale)
```